# Connecting elements with curved lines on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm looking for a lightweight library or code snippet to connect any two elements on a website with a curved line. The elements are not on a canvas - could be any DOM element - and the curved line should redraw when the browser window is resized.

An example of what I am trying to achieve can be seen here: http://tinypic.com/r/2cia0k8/9.

I've tried jsPlumb, but am looking for a more lightweight solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one do-it-yourself solution. Make an `svg` element that (invisibly) covers the entire document. Insert an svg `path` element whose start and end coordinates are calculated based on the positions of the div's to be connected, and whose curve is created in whatever way you want based on those start and end coordinates.

For the example below, click on "Run code snippet", then click on the "Full page" button, and then resize the window to see the effect.

The example has two div's connected via the middle of their horizontal insides edges. The details of the curve are, of course, up to you. The connector is constructed using the `d` attribute of the svg `path`. In this example, "M" is the "moveTo" coordinates where the path will start and the "C" points are the first and second control points and final coordinate for a cubic bezier curve. You'll have to [look those up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) to understand what they are, but they are a general way of creating smooth curves in an svg element.

A more complex document would need more care to determine the start and end coordinates of the svg `path` element, but this example at least gives you a place to begin.

```js
var divA      = document.querySelector("#a");
var divB      = document.querySelector("#b");
var connector = document.querySelector("#connector");

var drawConnector = function() {
  var posnA = {
    x: divA.offsetLeft + divA.offsetWidth,
    y: divA.offsetTop  + divA.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  var posnB = {
    x: divB.offsetLeft,
    y: divB.offsetTop  + divA.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  var dStr =
      "M" +
      (posnA.x      ) + "," + (posnA.y) + " " +
      "C" +
      (posnA.x + 100) + "," + (posnA.y) + " " +
      (posnB.x - 100) + "," + (posnB.y) + " " +
      (posnB.x      ) + "," + (posnB.y);
  connector.setAttribute("d", dStr);
};

window.addEventListener("resize", drawConnector);

drawConnector();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
#a {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
#b {
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <path id="connector" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
<div id="a">This is a regular HTML div.</div>
<div id="b">So is this.</div>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, this was *exactly* what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the extensive and creative solution.

Comment: My pleasure. I love the things svg can do, and I suspect a lot of developers aren't aware of its full potential.