# Creating a horizontally responsive chart/drawing with different statuses

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, apexcharts

I have 4 different statuses and I need to connect these together based on different conditions. The image shows all the possible scenarios for the 4 statuses. This graph/drawing should be horizontally responsive as well.

[image]

First I tried with pure CSS, but it fails to connect circles and keep the line curvature when the window size changes. Then I tried to create something similar with Apex charts but to no avail.

Also tried with the suggestion in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958751/connecting-elements-with-curved-lines-on-website), but it does not support the line curvature I need.

Is there a way to create this either with CSS or with a JS package?

Comment: Have you tried changing the line curvature? I don’t understand what you mean by ‘does not support the line curvature’. Please could you show the code you tried using an svg?